# Right to left Cocoa Touch interfaces

Tags: ios, uitableview, internationalization

How to create Cocoa Touch interfaces that supports right to left languages like Arabic and Hebrew?
UITableView is a clear example as it should change how it displays its rows.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research and it seems iPhone now supports arabic. Check out this [link](http://www.iphoneislam.com/2007/11/iphoneislam_arabic_keyboard/20). If you want to display the text towards the right, then you'll need to align the text towards right using

```
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
```

You can also check out this [cool feature](https://github.com/aakash272/Dynamic-information-display-on-touch-screen-phones) for tableViews.